# Retrofit/Android - dynamic response support

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having trouble with mapping resulting json data to pojo class with Retrofit. I need to determine Firebase topics by token. This can be eaisly done with Google's json api, as described here: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances

In my case, server response is simlar to this:

```
{
    "applicationVersion": "36",
    "connectDate": "2018-02-04",
    "attestStatus": "ROOTED",
    "application": "<my application id>",
    "scope": "*",
    "authorizedEntity": "205414012839",
    "rel": {
        "topics": {
            "topic1": {
                "addDate": "2018-02-04" 
            },
            "topic2": {
                "addDate": "2018-01-31" 
            }
        }
    },
    "connectionType": "WIFI",
    "appSigner": "<hash>",
    "platform": "ANDROID" 
}
```

The problem is basically `rel` and `topics` structure, because `topics` is dynamic and field list can by anything and it's unknown. So I can't generate simple POJO to get it mapped by Retrfofit automatically.

Can I force Retrofit to treat `topics` as single `String` field, I will able to parse it later to retrieve topics list? Or is there any other soulution?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you use gson, you can define rel as a JsonElement. If you use moshi, you can define it as a Map.
for gson:

```
public class Response{
    private String applicationVersion;
    private String connectDate;
    private String attestStatus;
    private String application;
    private String scope;
    private String authorizedEntity;
    private String connectionType;
    private String appSigner;
    private String platform;
    private JsonElement rel;
}
```

for moshi:

```
public class Response{
    private String applicationVersion;
    private String connectDate;
    private String attestStatus;
    private String application;
    private String scope;
    private String authorizedEntity;
    private String connectionType;
    private String appSigner;
    private String platform;
    private Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> rel;
}
```